# AngularJS and Google Charts (try to change graphs data dynamically)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm building a political quiz where depending of the answer of your questions, the position of the point in the graph will be changing.

As you can see here on the example:

http://elcerebrohabla.com/ideotemp/#/comenzar

There are two variables ("económico", and "social") whose value is changing according to the answers that the user is giving in the quiz. That values are saving in two scopes: $scope.contadoreco, and $scope.contadorsoc.

What I have to do if I want that the position of the point changes on the graph dinamically depending of the answers.

This is the code:

```
var aritmetica = angular.module('aritmetica', ['ngAnimate']);

aritmetica.factory("contadoreco",function(){
        return {};
});
aritmetica.factory("contadorsoc",function(){
        return {};
});


aritmetica.controller('encuestaController',  ['$scope', 'contadoreco', 'contadorsoc', function($scope,contadoreco,contadorsoc) {
  $scope.contadoreco= 0;
  $scope.contadorsoc= 0;
  $scope.pageClass = 'encuesta';
  $scope.sumareco = function(cantidad) { $scope.contadoreco += cantidad};
  $scope.restareco = function(cantidad) { $scope.contadoreco -= cantidad};
  $scope.sumarsoc = function(cantidad) { $scope.contadorsoc += cantidad};
  $scope.restarsoc = function(cantidad) { $scope.contadorsoc -= cantidad};
}]);

 aritmetica.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'contadoreco', 'contadorsoc', function($scope,contadoreco,contadorsoc) {
      $scope.name = "Name";
}]);

  aritmetica.directive('chart', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $elm, $attr) {
          // Create the data table.
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Económico', 'Social'],
    [$scope.contadoreco, $scope.contadorsoc]]);

          var options = {
    title: 'Age of sugar maples vs. trunk diameter, in inches',
    hAxis: {title: 'Económico', minValue: -130, maxValue: 130},
    vAxis: {title: 'Social', minValue: -130, maxValue: 130},
    legend: 'none',
    width: 400,
    height:400,
  };
          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart($elm[0]);
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    }
  });

  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['aritmetica']);
  });
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

Comment: A $watch on your directive in your scope to watch the variables that you need to update.  and then apply the changes to the google chart: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation

Comment: A lot of thanks, even though I could made the graph only with CSS manipulating the variables with AngularJS